# How can I sync my blockchain using only other computers on my LAN?

Tags: blockchain-data

I have two other computers which have synced blockchains on my LAN and would like to update the new blockchain using only data from the other computers on my LAN, so as to avoid extra external bandwidth use. How can I do this?

A workaround would be to copy the blockchain from one computer to the other, but I'd rather update the target blockchain instead of replacing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unplug/disconnect internet, `monerod --allow-local-ip --add-exclusive-node XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX`

With the exclusive argument you may not even need to uplug or disconnect from the internet.